# PHP big size file uploading issue

Tags: php, file-upload

We have a form where we can upload file. We are not able to upload big size files for e.g. > 30 MB.

We have already changed the settings memory_limit, post_max_size  and upload_max_filesize to some large number.

But still we get "This web page is not available" error with "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Chrome . In Chrome we see message like "Uploading %" and after certain %of uploading it throws the error. In short it seems data is itself not posting to action page.

Comment: have you any error in your php error.log file?

Comment: Seems more like the request was blocked by firewall or something else. What is your webserver setup, do you use any front proxy like `nginx`?

Comment: No errors found in log file

Comment: This issue has been resolved now. The error was due to MaxRequestLen set in mod_fcgid module. The error was "mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16785408 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216)". Now we changed the MaxRequestLen to 250 MB

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your upload is being timed out. Try increasing `max_input_time` in php.ini, ie:

`max_input_time = 600`

Comment: Yes it is already changed to 1800. Sorry I forgot to add this is my question

Answer (score 0):

and your php's max_execution_time = ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

perhaps better to show the code you're using.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST) {
print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

For larger file upload use chunk upload.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Hopefully this will help you.